# Why does a star with its core collapsing and about to undergo a supernova, explode, instead of rapidly collapsing all of its matter into a black hole?

Tags: black-holes, astrophysics, stars, supernova, stellar-evolution

I am guessing this has something to do with density.

I would assume that a massive star that has its core collapsing would be a prime candidate for having its core turn into a black-hole. If the core then turned into a black-hole, it would follow that subsequent mass would rapidly pass its event horizon and feed the black hole resulting in a rapidly expanding event horizon.

So why does a supernova occur at all? Why does the star not simply completely collapse into a black hole with no explosion when a star's core collapses?

Comment: My guess at an answer is that stars that are candidates for supernova, are too small/not massive enough to result in a black-hole.

Comment: Related, if not dupe of, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/99375/25301, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/407854/25301, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/63558/25301 and possibly others

Comment: Thank you. Those two questions in combination answer my question.