# Heavy elements creation

Tags: thermodynamics, nuclear-physics, astrophysics, fusion, elements

Would elements heavier than iron not be extremely rare if only created by supernovae?  I believe all elements above hydrogen are created in the star's corona. Hydrogen fusion is not possible in star's centre as pressure and temperature are relatively low and hydrogen would not gravitate  to that region. The surface of the sun is only 8000 K where the corona is about 15000000 K.

Comment: The centre of the Sun is hotter than (most of) the corona and it is about 12-13 orders of magnitude denser. Heavy elements are not only created in supernovae. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/7131/origin-of-elements-heavier-than-iron-fe?r=SearchResults

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Origin of elements heavier than Iron (Fe)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/7131/)

Comment: This doesn't seem like mainstream physics. Certainly not all elements above hydrogen are created in stars, let alone stellar corona. BBN for example created most of the universe's helium.

Comment: *"I believe all elements above hydrogen are created in the star's corona."* If that were the case, then we'd see the tell-tale gamma ray signature of electron + positron annihilation. Or are you also claiming that the [p-p chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton%E2%80%93proton_chain_reaction) is a fiction?

Answer (score 0):

A star's ability to synthesize elements heavier than helium depends on its mass. A star of sufficient size will indeed burn hydrogen all the way to iron in its core- but this will not happen in Our Mister Sun.